# Dual boot - cannot get to second grub menu (are my expectations wrong?)

Tags: linux, arch-linux, grub, uefi, artix-linux

I have two different distros installed. Os1 was installed by a gui installer first, with an efi partition and a system partition. Os2 is vanilla artix so I have set that up second using basestrap from the live environment.

so now I have an efi partition containing:

EFI/os1

EFI/os2

and then each os has its own partition with system files.

I have run grub-install from os2 (was already done on os1) and grub-config from both oses with os-prober on and each now has a grub directory with their own config.

Now at this point I am expecting to be able to go into my motherboard settings and select to either prioritize the os1 or os2 uefi and boot to their respective grub menus -which thanks to os prober I would expect to have options to go to either os.

This is not what is happening. I can see an option for both in the motherboard boot menu but when selecting os2 it seems to just skip over it and revert to os1's grub menu (which does indeed have the option for both oses and I can boot into both from there).

I simply want to know if what I am expecting (2 different grub menus) is the way things are supposed to work or have I misunderstood how grub and efi work together - Ive never bothered trying to run multiple grub menus before but have reason to now if possible.

Comment: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair   &           
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Thanks for the advice - neither of my installed os is ubuntu/debian, I have garuda (arch based) and artix (also arch-like), easiest option for me would be to create a usb and fire up the live ISO. However I notice you said not to do this - I'm assuming you want a log from the OS (with mount points, etc). There is a boot repair tool in my own repos but it doesn't have a similar report function. Would info from a bootable iso be of any use?

Comment: Do not know if Boot-Repair works from Arch or not. I expect it will, but may need one or more utility functions added? The only reason to use the ppa over Boot-Repair's ISO is that the ISO is not updated as frequently.  Boot-Repair updated & improved an old script that I still use. Script does not need gui. Updated fork  as original bootinfoscript does not seem to be maintained
https://github.com/arvidjaar/bootinfoscript  I now extract the B-I-S part of Boot-Repair which is the even more updated script. /usr/share/boot-sav/b-i-s-functions.sh 2 files now also.